# CoreMotion not working within Swift Playgrounds

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground, core-motion

```
import UIKit
import ARKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import SceneKit
import CoreMotion

class MyViewController: UIViewController {

let motionManager = CMMotionManager()
var timer: Timer!
var label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 400, width: 400, height: 100))

override func loadView() {

    let view = UIView()

    view.addSubview(label)
    label.text = "Show Yaw Here"
    self.view = view
    view.backgroundColor = .white

    motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
    motionManager.startGyroUpdates()
    motionManager.startMagnetometerUpdates()
    motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates()

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector: #selector(MyViewController.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func update() {
    self.label.text = "Obama"
    if let accelerometerData = motionManager.accelerometerData {
        print("Device Accelerometer: \(accelerometerData)")
    }
    if let gyroData = motionManager.gyroData {
        print("Device Gyro: \(gyroData)")
    }
    if let magnetometerData = motionManager.magnetometerData {
        print("Device Magnetometer: \(magnetometerData)")
    }
    if let deviceMotion = motionManager.deviceMotion {
        print("Device Motion: \(deviceMotion)")
        let yaw = (Int)(Double(floor(1000*deviceMotion.attitude.yaw)/1000) * 180.0/Double.pi)
        self.label.text = "Yaw: \(yaw) Degrees"
    }
}
}
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

This (above) is the code that I am using as a playground. I got the code directly from an iOS app and it works perfectly when I run the iOS app on the same device, which is an iPad from early 2018 running iOS 12. This is the code I used for the actual app which works perfectly on the iPad. All it does is write the Yaw value in degrees to a text box. I do not get errors or warnings when I run either of them. The view controller does show up in the playground and so does the initial label text, but the code doesn't update the device motion when I move the iPad, while it does update in the app version.

```
import UIKit
import CoreMotion

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let motionManager = CMMotionManager()
var timer: Timer!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    label.text = "ayy lmao"

    motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
    motionManager.startGyroUpdates()
    motionManager.startMagnetometerUpdates()
    motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates()

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func update() {
    if let accelerometerData = motionManager.accelerometerData {
        print("Device Accelerometer: \(accelerometerData)")
    }
    if let gyroData = motionManager.gyroData {
        print("Device Gyro: \(gyroData)")
    }
    if let magnetometerData = motionManager.magnetometerData {
        print("Device Magnetometer: \(magnetometerData)")
    }
    if let deviceMotion = motionManager.deviceMotion {
        print("Device Motion: \(deviceMotion)")
        let yaw = (Int)(deviceMotion.attitude.yaw * 180.0/Double.pi)
        self.label.text = "Yaw: \(yaw) Degrees"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what your actual question is

Comment: @JoakimDanielson what changes would I need to make to my playground so it works the exact same way as the app? I'm assuming I'm missing code that is necessary for a playground.

Comment: @RohithVishwajith are you trying to run the code in the iOS Playgrounds app on a real device? What happens when you run in a playground, is your view controller displayed at all, it just doesn't update the motion data?

Comment: Improve the question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55255580/edit) it instead of posting information as comments

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I made some edits to clarify the question, basically it won't update in the playground but it will in the app.

Answer (score 0):

The Core Location APIs are async, so you have to keep the playground running after you call startUpdatingLocation(). So give this a spin

```
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

More on [needsindefiniteExecution](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/playgroundsupport/playgroundpage/1964501-needsindefiniteexecution)

Comment: thanks for your response. It seems to be updating as a whole but devicemotion is the only one that doesn't update still.

Comment: is that the only one which is not working and all the other's are working? @RohithVishwajith

Comment: I just checked if my label text updates with the others and it does, so that seems to be the case.

Comment: do you know if is there any other way I can get the yaw of the iPad in playgrounds? DeviceMotion doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @RohithVishwajith  Maybe the reason why you are not seeing that information could be because playground does not use info plist where you register why you are using core motion, check the official docs https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion

Comment: Would it be possible to add the plist to the playground so it works? Or perhaps modify the original plist?

Comment: @RohithVishwajith playground don’t have plist, adding them to the project does not cause them to access the info.plist file. My question to you is that if it’s working in xcode what’s the motivation behind doing this exercise via playground?

Answer (score 0):

Core motion framework works fine on Swift Playgrounds app on iPad for all services other than Device Motion. `StartDeviceMotionUpdates(to:){}` fails to deliver any updates. Sadly I have found no explanation as to why this should be! The GPS can, of course, only be accessed via `CoreLocation` and that requires security validation not available on the app, so no way to access GPS data either.